# Sails.js: how to populate array using model associations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I'm using  "sails": "~0.10.0-rc5", "sails-mongo": "^0.10.0-rc3".
I have 2 models: Invoice, Item.

*Invoice model*

```
Invoice: {
    name: 'sample 1',
    items: [1,2] // 1,2 is id of Item model
}
```

*Item model*

```
Item {
    id: 1,
    name: "king"
}
Item {
    id: 2,
    name: 'queen'
}
```

**I want the result to be:**

```
Invoice: {
    name: 'sample 1',
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "king"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'queen'
    }]
}
```

I read [model associations from the sails docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/ModelAssociations.md) but i don't know how to use it in my situation.

Comment: could you share the solution if you managed to find one?

Answer (score 1):

Your *item* model will look like this:

```
attributes: {
    name: "STRING"
    // You don't need the ID field as this is automatically created for you
}
```

Your *invoice* model will look like this:

```
attributes: {
    name: "STRING"
    items: {
        collection: "item",
        via: "item"
    }
}
```

Now create a few documents of the *item* model.

```
sails> ModelNameOfItem.create({name:'MyFirstItem'}).exec(console.log)
null { name: 'MyFirstItem',
  createdAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:45:33 GMT-0600 (CST),
  updatedAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:45:33 GMT-0600 (CST),
  _id: "some_id_created_by_mongo" }
```

Now create a document of the *invoice* model.

```
sails> ModelNameOfInvoice.create({name:'MyFirstInvoice', items:"the_id from_item_created"}).exec(console.log)
null { name: 'MyFirstInvoice',
  createdAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:45:33 GMT-0600 (CST),
  updatedAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:45:33 GMT-0600 (CST),
  _id: "some_id_created_by_mongo" }
```

Thats all! To query this, use the `populate` method.

```
sails> Invoice.find({name:'MyFirstInvoice'}).populate('items').exec(console.log);
```

Comment: Hi display_name:
I try, but it doesn't work with array of item. It just work on item.

Comment: @user3487954 I updated my answer to include the `collection` and `via` attribute. The code is not tested, but fetched from the sailsjs documentation. Should work :)

Comment: In the Invoice.create, Shouldn't items:"the_id from_item_created" be items:["the_id from_item_created"]?

Comment: @aludvigsen the question clearly states it requires an array of items. This answer is only re-inventing the wheel!

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is:
in invoice model:

```
...
items: {
  collection: 'item'
}
```

Comment: I do not know how I can get this to work. Is that really supported. @Thinh Pham can you point us at any official sails documentation